# Yii2: How to add users manually

Tags: php, yii

Can users be added manually from the database? I was given a project made in this framework but the client does not remember the access codes to the administrator, and I already tried to create the user manually but I do not know how to encrypt the password.

Comment: is there already an admin/user login that you can use?

Comment: Yes, there are a admin page, I'm trying locate a recovery password page, I'm really noob with yii2  framework, What do you think about a quick solve while I try understand the  framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adding Manually

Yes you can add a user manually from the database too, all you need is the encrypted password that you can generate using the following line

```
echo Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash('Your_password');
```

Now either you can copy paste the above line inside an existing view file and copy the output string and save as password in the user table `password` field.

### Using Migration

Or [create a migration](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations) and add the admin user via that migration for quick fix you can copy paste the following migration into your `migrations` folder it should be on the root for the `basic-app` or `console/migrations` for the `advance-app`.

Note: change the column and/or table names if they are different in your case i have used `user` and `profile` table names

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Class m180322_183353_add_admin_user
 */
class m180322_183353_add_admin_user extends Migration
{
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

    /**
     * Table name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $_user = "{{%user}}";

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $_profile = "{{%profile}}";

    /**
     * Runs for the migate/up command
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $time = time();
        $password_hash = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash('pass12345');
        $auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        $table = $this->_user;

        $sql = <<<SQL
        INSERT INTO {$table}
        (`username`, `email`,`password_hash`, `auth_key`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
        VALUES
        ('admin', 'admin@yoursite.com',  '$password_hash', '$auth_key', {$time}, {$time})
SQL;
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();

        $id = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();

        //add profile entry for admin
        $this->insert(
            $this->_profile,
            [
                'user_id' => $id,
                'name' => 'Administrator',
                'public_email' => 'admin@yoursite.com'
            ]
        );

    }

    /**
     * Runs for the migate/down command
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function safeDown()
    {
        $table = $this->_user;
        $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT id from {$table}
        where username='admin'
SQL;
        $id = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
        $this->delete($this->_user, ['username' => 'admin']);
        $this->delete($this->_profile, ['user_id' => $id]);
    }

}
```

Now go to your project root via terminal and run the following command

```
./yii migrate
```

it will show you something like below

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.22)

Total 1 new migration to be applied:
        m180322_183353_add_admin_user

Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:
```

Type yes and hit enter, if all goes well it will show you output onthe terminal like below

```
Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:yes
*** applying m180322_183353_add_admin_user
    > insert into {{%profile}} ... done (time: 0.006s)
*** applied m180322_183353_add_admin_user (time: 0.865s)


1 migration was applied.

Migrated up successfully.
```

Now you can login with the following credentials

```
username : admin
password: pass12345
```

If you want to remove the user in future type the following in terminal, and remove the migration afterwards once it runs

```
./yii migrate/down 1
```

considering that you havent created any other migration after this, or create a separate one to remove the user.

Answer (score 0):

On PHP 5.5+ Yii 2 uses [`password_hash()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate passwords hashes. If you want to reset someone's password, you can generate new hash from console:

```
php -r 'echo password_hash("my password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT), "\n";'
```

And use generated value in update query.